Firebase-admin sdk for Python raise error "StreamGenerator" is not iterable
Previously(a week ago) my Python code for communicating with Firestore works perfectly fine. But today I started working on it again, it raise error when iterating the collection.stream()
    service_account = credentials.Certificate('credential/serviceAccount.json')
    firebase_admin.initialize_app(service_account)

    firestore_db = firestore.client()

    docs = firestore_db.collection("FeatureCollection").stream()
    for doc in docs:
        print(doc)

The error is raised at for doc in *docs*.
the error is "StreamGenerator" is not iterable "__next__" method not defined on type "DocumentSnapshot".
Additionally, whenever I execute the request for document, such as
doc = firestore_db.collection("FeatureCollection").document("geom1").get()

It also raise error about gRPC which I am not familiar at all.
# Error
WARNING: All log messages before absl::InitializeLog() is called are written to STDERR
I0000 00:00:1721882710.133005 19720588 config.cc:230] gRPC experiments enabled: call_status_override_on_cancellation, event_engine_dns, event_engine_listener, http2_stats_fix, monitoring_experiment, pick_first_new, trace_record_callops, work_serializer_clears_time_cache
I0000 00:00:1721882710.140969 19720588 check_gcp_environment_no_op.cc:29] ALTS: Platforms other than Linux and Windows are not supported


Found the solution, it is the same as this issue.
I have to set a few of environment variables:
export GRPC_PYTHON_BUILD_SYSTEM_OPENSSL=1
export GRPC_PYTHON_BUILD_SYSTEM_ZLIB=1
